# How to log in to Flash and Javascript sites

Tags: python, flash, selenium

I was trying to log in to a website using Selenium, but it is using Flash and Javascript. How can I use Selenium to log in to Flash and Javascript websites?

The website is "https :// trade. login and trade. com /fin spreads /" sorry about the spaces

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use selenium to click on a swf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821899/use-selenium-to-click-on-a-swf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I use Selenium to log in to Flash and Javascript websites?

The answer is: **You cannot**.  Selenium cannot interact with embedded elements such as Flash, PDF's, or Java Applets.

Comment: if there anyway of interacting with embedded elements using python